# Custom options during RPM install with rpmbuild

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I would like to use custom options during RPM install. I use rpmbuild to craft the RPM so I have the SPEC file.
Can I define my own option that I can use in the SPEC file (e.g. `rpm -i --r_password=something acme-1.1-1.el7.noarch.rpm` and the value of **r_password** will be put to a file -> controlled by in the `%post` section in the SPEC file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. You can use macros in %post. But they are evaluated during build time and you can only override it during build time:

```
%{!?foo:%global foo SOME_DEFAULT}

%post
echo %{foo}
```

The first line defines some default when macro `foo` is not present.

Then you can run:

```
rpmbuild -ba --define='foo bar' evil.spec
```

where you define your own macro `foo` with the content `bar`. After the rpm is built then everything is put into stone and you cannot change the rpm.

But you can do something like:

```
%post
cat /etc/myconfig.cfg | ... #do something based on content of the file
```

and the tell user to:

```
echo foo > /etc/myconfig.cfg; rpm -i acme-1.1-1.el7.noarch.rpm
```